# Res.locals.apsinlge not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, twig, swig-template

I am trying to use `apsingle` in my template but it is not working. I get the correct data when I `console.log(apsingle);` but inside the template it just isn't working at all. It return

Partial route:

```
(req, res, next) => {
      AP.findById(req.params.id).exec(function(err, foundAP){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.locals.apsingle =  foundAP;
        }
    });
    next();
    }
```

Loop and if statement inside template:

```
{% if apsingle %}
   {%  for ap in apsingle  %}
     <tr>
      <td>{{ap.type}}</td>
      <td>{{ap.model}}</td>
      <td>{{ap.notes}}</td>
     </tr>
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

If I do a test of:

```
{% if apsingle == null %}
<h1>I'm NULL</h1>
{% endif %}
```

Then it outputs it, so the `apsingle` is coming through to the template as `null`.

Output asked for by Andy:

```
{ _id: objectID,
  type: 'ap',',
  model: ';lkj;l',

  notes: '',
  __v: 0,
  author:  id: someID
}
```

Error mentioned to Andy:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as tpl] (eval at <anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/asset-management/node_modules/swig/lib/swig.js:498:13), <anonymous>:10:1706)
    at compiled (/home/ubuntu/workspace/asset-management/node_modules/swig/lib/swig.js:619:18)
    at Object.eval [as tpl] (eval at <anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/asset-management/node_modules/swig/lib/swig.js:498:13), <anonymous>:7:154)
    at compiled (/home/ubuntu/workspace/asset-management/node_modules/swig/lib/swig.js:619:18)
    at /home/ubuntu/workspace/asset-management/node_modules/swig/lib/swig.js:559:20
    at /home/ubuntu/workspace/asset-management/node_modules/swig/lib/swig.js:690:9
    at tryToString (fs.js:456:3)
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:443:12)
```

Comment: can't you like write a method `getFields` and do a foreach on that in the template? I'm assuming `ap` is an object right?

Comment: Sorry but your question and information you've provided is quite unclear, or maybe just not organized well.  Also, this is quite literally a duplicate of this same question you asked a few days ago, under some new user ID:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46817620/show-content-only-for-that-user/46818840?noredirect=1#comment80623733_46818840

Comment: @dvsoukup How can I make the question suit your desires? Same question? I never posted on here until today when I created the account. Before Stack Overflow I have been using reddit as help. Thought I would try Stack Overflow and from my first question I thought wow quick responses that were helpful. Your comment not so much.

Comment: @Kirbytech I'm not trying to shoot you down, just raise issues. You need to list all the relevant pieces of information here before anyone can give you anywhere near a decent answer.  For example, show an example of the contents of `apsingle`.  Where is the `apsingle` object within your template getting populated?  Is there more to your route we need to know?  Right now it uses `next()` which is really more for use of middlewares.  So you could be quite literally jumping to some other function and returning a response prior to `apsingle` being populated....

Comment: @dvsoukup Did you look at the updated OP? I added sample output and I also changed the question to be more direct and I can ask the other stuff separate if need be. It does use `next()` becasuse there is something going on below it but it is just sending a bunch of logs to a file that are not related to the exact data but are related to the request, like method, response time, db query time, route, middleware called. None of which is even related other than the route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful of scope, having it inside one bracket that you don't mean it to be causes a lot of issues.

Started:

```
(req, res, next) => {
      AP.findById(req.params.id).exec(function(err, foundAP){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.locals.apsingle =  foundAP;
        }
    });
    next();
    }
```

Solved:

```
(req, res, next) => {
  AP.findById(req.params.id).exec(function(err, foundAP){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        res.locals.apsingle =  foundAP;
    }
});
}
next();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try rendering a page to troubleshoot. Maybe you need a different approach, create another file and try to populate it. Then you can try again with res.locals

```
(req, res, next) => {
  AP.findById(req.params.id, (err, foundAP) => {
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log(foundAP);
        res.render('yourview', {apsingle : foundAP)
    }
});
next();
}
```

In your view try this. You are not pulling an array of object, but just one. You don't need to loop thru it.

```
{% if apsingle %}
 <tr>
  <td>{{apsingle.type}}</td>
  <td>{{apsingle.model}}</td>
  <td>{{apsingle.notes}}</td>
 </tr>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Explain what you mean please? The code you posted is what I have, yes. It seems to sorta work, when I console.log `apsingle` it logs the correct data but when I go inside my template I can't access the data. I have done res.locals.custom before in a different file and can access that just fine.

Comment: what is the output structure of your foundAP?

Comment: Tried that and got `TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined` I got this error before so I went and found (don't remember the site exactly) some middleware that let's me do a `sendRenderFile` and it is pretty much just a `res.render`

Comment: Well, then there is something else. On the output you posted, your object has no property 'name'. We need to know what file and line that is returning the error.

Comment: I realized the loop I had in the OP originally had old code I deleted when trying to debug this so the `name` property is gone. Anyways the error is in the OP now. Too long to fit here under the character limit.

Comment: See edited post. You are just pulling one object not an array of that. You don't need to loop thru.

Comment: I am trying to load a completely different route now and am getting `Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`. My route is as basic and I could get, the route path, then the code from your answer but with `next` and `next()` removed. Changed the view path to the correct one and failure. Error 500..  I changed the content of the view file to be just my blank template file and it still fails, changed to render a file I know works and same result.

Comment: I tried this exact route and same error as in my last comment `// show single model  
  app.get('/dashboard/it/model/:id',
    (req, res) => {
        res.render('dashboard/it/singleModel');
    });`

Comment: just put back to what it was with res.locals when you were getting NULL, and with the changes we made and the view without the loop. It should work like that. If does not, you need to upload the code to github for a better view. But try first the changes I told you. As for rendering the view path, that should be put into another question if not answered yet in stackoverflow.

Comment: I have removed the loop and tried `{% if apsingle %}
                <h1>APSINGLE WORKS!!!</h1>
              {% endif %}` to see if that would even work, no luck.

Comment: I am working on that, I don't want to open my private repo so I am only uploading some files. It might take a while.

Comment: In the mean time, this works just fine so maybe res.locals doesn't like `foundAP`?

Comment: `res.render()`? It give the `TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined` again

Comment: So I have figured out it is a scope issue. If I put it inside the else of the callback for the findById it fails but if I put it above the query it works. I did change my query a bit to match what the solution in the post linked above used. Same results. SOmething about  the ` AP.find` scope is the problem

Comment: I solved it, the `next();` was in the wrong spot. I was right on the scope issue, next needed to be moved inside the final bracket.

Comment: Good deal, and you didn't need to loop thru the data in the view correct?

Comment: Nope didn't need to, I tried and it didn't work well. I did have the same error in another route and in that case I did create an array and loop through it.

Comment: You are just pulling one Object,  you don't need to waste a loop thru it or an array for the matter but you can you can call it directly like  {{array[0].item1}}, {{ array[0].item2}} etc